# Can this code be reduced and still have the same effect?

Tags: css, button

Is any of the code below unnecessary? I think I have more than required or perhaps not followed best practice here.

```
#button {
    color: #fff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #grey;
    padding: 1%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Avenir;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure we can judge this from your code alone. For example, you use color: #fff !important, which means that you're overriding other CSS. Many of these lines can only be understood in context. 
As a sidenote, if you want to reduce the number of lines in your code, you can research shorthand for font and margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use font shorthand.

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;
```

So for your case:

```
font: bold 20px Avenir;
```

You can refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties for other shorthand properties to make your CSS more clean and compact.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could have been more compact if used

```
margin: 0 auto;
```